# Select only one Product with MAX(Id) for each Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I know this is apparently a very common issue, but despite all my search here and on Google, I am not able to adapt my findings to my case.

I thought it would be very simple but I am new to SQL and I'm afraid I don't get the logic for this one.

Basically, this is my data set: 
list of folios (Client), by date , an ID for each folio and date and if a folio gets modified, the previous one is kept but new lines are added for the same Folio and ID is incremental.

```
Date       | Client | ProductCode | ID |  Price
-----------|--------|-------------|----|--------
2019-01-01 |   C1   |      A      | 1  |  100
2019-01-02 |   C1   |      A      | 2  |  100
2019-01-03 |   C1   |      B      | 3  |  100
2019-01-01 |   C1   |      A      | 4  |  150
2019-01-02 |   C1   |      A      | 5  |  150
2019-01-03 |   C1   |      B      | 6  |  150
2019-01-02 |   C2   |      B      | 1  |  150
2019-01-02 |   C2   |      X      | 2  |  150
```

The desired output is: for one given date, if I have twice the same folio, I want the most recent (highest ID) only, with the corresponding Price (and eventually some extra columns)

```
Date       | Client | ProductCode | ID |  Price
-----------|--------|-------------|----|--------
2019-01-01 |   C1   |      A      | 4  |  150
2019-01-02 |   C1   |      A      | 5  |  150
2019-01-03 |   C1   |      B      | 6  |  150
2019-01-02 |   C2   |      X      | 2  |  150
```

I've tried going with:

```
SELECT Date, Client, ProductCode , Price, MAX(ID)
From myTable
Group BY Date, Client, ProductCode , Price
```

In the case I have twice the same line (with different ID), it works, but if one value is different (e.g Price), then I get both.

I have then tried to go with `ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Client ORDER BY ID)` and then select MAX, but I am just creating a new ID and goes back to square one.

I have found many questions about this, but usually with simplified exemples and as soon as I add my extra columns, then I get more lines than I should.

Thank you

Comment: why do you have three rows in the expected result for `folio = C1`? because they have the same price as the latest `id = 6`?

Comment: @RadimBača I have 3 rows because 3 different dates for Client C1 (each dates appearing twice). I want to filter out the 6 rows to keep only the one with the highest ID date by date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many ways to do the same, one of those is to use a row_number function

```
WITH C AS(
SELECT Date
     , Client
     , ProductCode 
     , Price
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION DATE, FOLIO, PRODUCTCODE ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RN 
From myTable
)
SELECT Date
     , Client
     , ProductCode 
     , Price
FROM C 
WHERE RN = 1
```

What you have to do in this case is create a CTE(It works like a subquery but more readeable) then apply row_number and partition your rows by date,folio,productcode and order it by id, this is going to return you your current list with a rn then filter rn, something good about this is that rn for each case are not repeating.

Answer (score 3):

Use `where` to select the rows you want.  One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from myTable t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id)
              from mytable t2
              where t2.date = t.date and t2.client = t.client
             );
```

With an index on `(client, date, id)`, this should have very good performance.